# have you a good example of a class booking system

Tags: e-commerce

I am redeveloping a booking system for a cookery school. Does anyone have any particularly good examples of good UI booking engines for courses or classes?

Comment: comment: the client has attached a default shopping cart system to the site and this seems wrong since users will most likely buy only one item - a course; the concept of shopping cart seems overkill if you ask me...

Answer (score 1):

checkout the systems that [www.bookinglive.co.uk](http://www.bookinglive.co.uk) have - a range of different online booking experiences to give you ideas for courses etc.